# For which values of $x$ the inequality $\frac{4e^{x/2} + 3}{x} >0$ holds.

Tags: analysis, inequality

For which values of $x$ the inequality $$\frac{4e^{x/2}  + 3}{x} >0$$ holds. Can someone help me for this? Thank you.

Comment: This one wouldn't have elementary solution, you'd have to use lambert W function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: is this not true for all $x > 0$

Comment: Does it have minimum this function?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $4e^{x/2}+3$ is always positive. So, the answer is $x\gt 0$.

Comment: @Venera : The minimum is about $6.78$ when $x\approx 2.44$. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284e%5E%28x%2F2%29%2B3%29%2Fx).